# C# .Net Standard HttpClient Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on a .Net Standard class library and working on creating a library for the new Destiny 2 Api. I have one method working which is the search for a user to get their information. However, when I make a request to a different endpoint I get this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a
>   stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see
>   inner exception. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation
>   has been canceled

I can send this request just fine using PostMan or any other Api testing tool so something must be wrong with my code. Something worth noting, when using other Api tools I notice that I get redirected a few times. Also when using Fiddler I can see that none of the requests actually get Json back, they all look like redirects to another page, Postman shows 3 redirects fiddler shows 2 and then a failure in my code.

My code is pretty small so I cannot think of much that could be breaking it:

```
public string GetProfile(BungieMembershipType membershipType, string destinyMembershipId)
{
    var properUrl = String.Format(GetProfileUrl, (int)membershipType, destinyMembershipId);
    var rawData = RootRequest.Web.GetStringAsync(properUrl).Result;
    return rawData;
}
```

The only thing that seems odd to me is I am testing my code inside of Unit Tests, I cannot evaluate `RootRequest` during the debugging. RootRequest is a static class that has a static HttpClient on it that is used for making all requests to keep authentication to the Api simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that something is actually wrong internally at the Bungie Api servers but multiple things about my code had to change. Firstly, my BaseUri was missing the `www.`. Secondly, the `GetProfileUrl` was missing a `/` before the `?queryString` was added.